# What are some unanswered questions in electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, soft-question, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

What don't we know about how electricity and/or magnetism works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't really understand why charge is quantized. Nor we do know if there ought to be magnetic monopoles.  These two things seem linked. [Dirac gave an argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Dirac.27s_quantization) for charge quantization in the early days, but this presupposed the existence of a magnetic monopole.  In Maxwell's equations, it would be completely natural to imagine the existence of magnetic monopoles, and some high energy theories predict their existence, but we've seen no direct evidence of them yet.  And to my knowledge, though it's not my area of expertise, I don't think there have been any other really compelling arguments for charge quantization to compete with Dirac's original proposal.

We also don't understand [high temperature superconductivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity) yet.

We also have a hard time computing electronic energy bands for complicated structures. Current [Density Functional Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory) techniques have errors on the percent level.

Comment: Numerical solutions to Maxwell's equations are generally very hard to come up with that get all the physics right correctly. That correspondence is still very much an open question with serious implications for plasma physics.